# In FabricJS how do I stop object from jumping 'to top' on selection

Tags: fabricjs

When you select an object with FabricJS the depth is changed so that it appears on top of everything else. I'd like to stop this from happening.

The selection border and handles should be on top, but the object itself should be behind the other objects so that users can see how it will be positioned once they have finished moving it around.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've now found out the answer. You have to pass `preserveObjectStacking = true` to the constructor.

eg

```
canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('YOUR_CANVAS_NAME', {preserveObjectStacking: true});
```